# vSphere SDK- How to Create user in Guest OS?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vsphere-client

I am using vSphere 5 java SDK for provision vmware. I could able to create Linux vmware. But I want to create users inside the newly created Guest vmware?

Is there any API to create users?

Answer (score 1):

Such an API does not exist. This needs to be handled outside of the vSphere framework itself. Using a follow-on script to handle post-startup config is a pretty solid way of handling further customizations needed.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using the StartProgramInGuest method in GuestProcessManager.

http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc_50/vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.html

See this tread for an example:

http://communities.vmware.com/message/1836761